# db2 transaction hangs when terminating debug session on client

Tags: database, windows, debugging, db2

I'm in visual studio debugging a .NET program with DB2 connection.
When I terminate the debug session, the open DB2 transaction remains active on the database server. The DB2 client seems not to recognize that I terminate my program (because I end the debug session).

Is there any db2 parameter like transaction timeout, query timeout or similiar to force open transactions to end when db2 client processes "die" ?

Best regards
Oliver

Comment: May be it has something to do with .Net connection pooling? Does the connection remain open after you exit Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, the connection is still alive and tables updated before are locked. Other clients cannot access this table and are getting an interrupt (sqlcode -952)